# except alternative on mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I need to have first select values that are not in the second select.

```
select tnum,user from resp order by tnum, user
except
select test.tnum,cursa.user from cursa inner join test on test.curso = cursa.curso;
```

results:

```
select tnum,user from resp order by tnum, user;=
tnum    user
1       1
1       7
1       8
1       10
2       7

select test.tnum,cursa.user from cursa inner join test on test.curso = cursa.curso;=
tnum    user
1       1
1       7
1       8
1       10
2       1
2       8
3       1
3       7
3       8
3       10
4       1
4       7
4       8
4       10
```

> I need of return tnum 2 and user 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would often be solved using `not exists`:

```
select r.tnum, r.user
from resp r
where not exists (select 1
                  from cursa c inner join
                       test t
                       on t.curso = c.curso
                  where t.tnum = r.tnum and c.user = r.user
                 );
```

This has a slight difference in how it handles `NULL` values.  If either `rep.tnum` or `resp.user` are `NULL`, then the row will not be removed.

If this is a possibility, then change the `where` clause in the subquery to:

```
where (t.tnum = r.tnum or (t.tnum is null and r.tnum is null) ) and
      (c.user = r.user or (c.user is null and r.user is null) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select tnum, user 
from resp AS t1
left join (
   select test.tnum, cursa.user 
   from cursa 
   inner join test 
   on test.curso = cursa.curso ) AS t2
ON t1.tnum = t2.tnum AND t1.user = t2.user
WHERE t2.num IS NULL AND t2.user IS NULL
order by tnum, user
```

The `WHERE` clause filters out all rows of `resp` that are related to rows of the derived table.